# Generic collection & wildcard in java

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I am having problems getting my head around generics in the following situation, see inline comments below for my questions:

```
public void exampleMethod() {
    //Intuitively I would expect this to mean that test is set containing objects 
    //that subclass AbstractGroup
    Set<? extends AbstractGroup> test;

    //Yet the compiler complains here and I do not understand why?

    test.add(new AnyAbstractGroupSubGroup());

    //I would guess that a method call such as this at runtime

    test = new HashSet<SubGroupA>()

    //would mean that only objects of subgroupA can be added to the collection, but then
    //what is the point in using the wildcard in the first place?  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//Intuitively I would expect this to mean that test is set containing objects 
//that subclass AbstractGroup
Set<? extends AbstractGroup> test;
```

Nope, it means that it's a set of one specific ? which extends AbstractGroup. And neither you nor the Compiler have any way of knowing what that ? is, so there's no way you can add anything to that Set.

You can assign the set's values to variables of type AbstractGroup, but not the other way around.

Instead, you need this:

```
Set<? super AbstractGroup> test;
```

This principle is sometimes called [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) and explained well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs/2723538#2723538).

Answer (score 4):

> `Set<? extends AbstractGroup> test;`

This means your set can be a set of any object that extends `AbstractGroup`, but normally the compiler would not allow you to add something to that set (since it can't tell whether you'd for example add a `SubGroupB` to a `Set<SubGroupA>` etc.).

> `test = new HashSet<SubGroupA>()`

Your actual set would only contain objects of type `SubGroupA` and subclasses thereof.
However, the compiler would still not know what the content of `test` would be (see above).

The point of the wild card is: you can assign any set to the variable that is parameterized with `AbstractGroup` or a subclass, thus assuring you can cast all objects *already in* that map to `AbstractGroup` (which the compiler checks for).

If you want to have a set that can contain any `AbstractGroup` object, just don't use the wildcard.

```
//this would compile (under the assumption that SubGroupA extends AbstractGroup)
Set<? extends AbstractGroup> test = new HashSet<SubGroupA>(); 

//this wouldn't compile, since the compiler doesn't know the type of test (it might change at runtime etc.)
test.add(new SubGroupA());


//this wouldn't compile since AbstractGroup and SubGroupA are not the exact same type (hence the wildcard would be needed here)
Set<AbstractGroup> test = new HashSet<SubGroupA>();

//this would compile
Set<AbstractGroup> test = new HashSet<AbstractGroup>();
test.add(new SubGroupA());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need wildcards here In your case it would suffice to say

```
Set<AbstractGroup> test;
```

And you can then put any subclass of AbstractGroup into the set.

Also, it doesn't look like you're initializing test in your code above.